# problema utilizando jquery con npm

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un problema al llamar a jquery. En mi proyecto tengo instalado npm, con el package.json, ahí tengo ingresada la dependencia de jquery. 
también estoy llamando al script 'bundle.js' de BUDO (node_modules).
Cuestión, dentro mi archivo principal 'index.js' , necesito declarar a jquery llamandolo con un require (al menos, así lo hice con el paquete simple-peer), el tema es que no sé cómo llamarlo, como definirlo para que me funcione, si me pueden ayudar, desde ya les agradezco. Les dejo el código abajo de mi index.js

```
var getUserMedia = require('getusermedia')

getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function (err, stream) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  var JQ = require('jquery')
  var jq = new JQ()

  $('#yourMessage').val('hola')

  var Peer = require('simple-peer')
  var peer = new Peer({
    initiator: location.hash === '#init',
    trickle: false,
    stream: stream
  })

  peer.on('signal', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('yourId').value = JSON.stringify(data)
  })

  document.getElementById('connect').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var otherId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('otherId').value)
    peer.signal(otherId)
  })

  document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var yourMessage = document.getElementById('yourMessage').value
    peer.send(yourMessage)
  })

  peer.on('data', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('messages').textContent += data + '\n'
  })

  peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
    var video = document.createElement('video')
    document.body.appendChild(video)

    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
    video.play()
  })
})
```

ahí tengo $('#yourMessage').val('hola') , pero me indica que '$' no es una función

Comment: Cambia tu require a `$ = require('jquery');`, es todo.

Comment: Era tan simple, pero me carcomía la duda, mil gracias!

Comment: No debiera ser necesario invocar a un constructor para obtener una instancia de jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia tu require a `$ = require('jquery');` y es todo.

Si estas utilizando webpack puedes utilizar el ProvidePlugin que automáticamente carga los modulos sin necesidad de utilizar `import/require`. Esto en `webpack.config.js`.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me va a facilitar mucho el trabajo eso.