# Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, npm, electron

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con electron y tengo un archivo html, index.html, que me carga la lógica de mi aplicación que la tengo en un archivo, logicAndInterface.js.
Estoy usando bootstrap pero no entiendo por qué me sale el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery
> must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.

He probado tres soluciones distintas:

- **usar un CDN**: Por cierto la conexión a Internet me funciona y pruebo con el CDN de google, ya que no encuentro los CDN propios de jquery en el sitio de jquery.com:

  ```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  ```
- **Instalar jquery con npm**: Trayéndome el archivo mediante una etiqueta script desde los node modules:

  ```
    <script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  ```
- **Poner el archivo jquery-3.5.1.js en el mismo directorio que index.html**:

  ```
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  ```

Además de estas acciones que he llevado a cabo me he leído la pregunta:
[problema utilizando jquery con npm](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115544/problema-utilizando-jquery-con-npm) pero hacer `$ = require('jquery');` en mi archivo `logicAndInterface.js` no me ha servido como tampoco hacerlo desde `index.js` que es el archivo desde el cual electron lanza la aplicación. La otra opción que me da esta pregunta es usar webpack pero yo no quiero tener que usarlo para este caso.

Mi código html:

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<title>MemoryAssistant</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 offset-lg-2 pt-4 pb-4">
      <canvas id="chart-area"  width="300" height="300" class="chartjs-render-monitor"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="parentpannel" class="col-12 col-lg-4 pt-4 pb-4">
      <div class="container-fluid" id="pannel-next-question" style="background-color:yellow">hola
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12 col-lg-2 offset-lg-5 pt-4 pb-4">
    <div id="start-button">
     </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="question-text-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="answer-text-container"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="button-container" class="col-12 col-lg-2 offset-lg-5 pt-4 pb-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <button id="save-button"  class="btn btn-success" onclick='fsSaveData()'>save your results</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> -->
<script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="logicAndInterface.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

El código de mi proyecto: [Memory Assistant está disponible en Github](https://github.com/GuillermoBaldan/Memory-Assistant/tree/master).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He cambiado la respuesta para que sea mas acertada he montado en mi caso una mini aplicación en github y esta es la forma en la que lo tengo yo
Como ves requiero con primero con $ jquery luego requiero popper y luego bootstrap

```
<title>Recetero</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="../../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css"
/>
<!-- Bootstrap Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script>
  let $ = require("jquery");
</script>
<script>
  require("popper.js");
</script>
<script>
  require("bootstrap");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/paneles.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/navbar.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/paneles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/switch.css" />
```

esto seria mi index.html te dejo mi packaje.json porque en mi caso yo meti como dependencia  jquery

```
{
  "name": "RECETERO-ELECTRO-APP",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.2",
    "animate.css": "^4.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0", /*lo meto como dependencia con npm */
    "electron": "^9.0.4",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "promise-mysql": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

Espero que sea de utilidad

He de decir que existen errores de recarga de jquery y no existe un soporte completo por lo menos cuando lo lo use.

Comment: He probado el orden que me has dicho: Primero jquery, Segundo mi archivo haciendo dentro de el $ = requiere('jquery), tercero popper y cuarto bootstrap y aún así no funciona. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: @Mr.Baldan he añadido información completa en la respuesta espero que esta vez te sea de ayuda

Comment: ¿Por favor podrías poner el enlace a Github?

Comment: te dejo el link => https://github.com/stealman364/Recetero-Electron  @Mr.Baldan